# How to use aggregate functions on joined tables with filters in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy, aggregate-functions, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to produce results from the following tables that I want to join with SQLALCHEMY (or textual SQL methods).

```
class Requisition(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'requisition'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_no = Column(Float)

class Budget(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'budget'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    budget_line = Column(String)
    amount = Column(Numeric(12,2))
    requisition_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('requisition.id'))
    requisition = relationship(Requisition)
```

My goal is to join these tables such that I can filter the joined tables by requisition.order_no and return values grouped by budget.budget_line with sums of budget.amount. I've tried a million ways to write this an i get a variety of errors. Here's my latest attempt:

```
def sum_budgets_original_budget(current_order_no):
    budgets_query = session.query(Budget.budget_line, Requisition, func.sum(Budget.amount)).group_by(Budget.budget_line)\
       .filter(text("order_no<=:current_order_no")).params(current_order_no=current_order_no).all()
  return dict(budgets_query)
```

Here the error I am getting. (I removed a couple of unncessary columns from the tables above that are not affecting the error but you can see them referenced in the exception response.)

ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "requisition.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT budget.budget_line AS budget_budget_line, requisition... ^ 'SELECT budget.budget_line AS budget_budget_line, requisition.id AS requisition_id, requisition.order_no AS requisition_order_no, requisition.requisition_name AS requisition_requisition_name, requisition.created_date AS requisition_created_date, requisition.modified_date AS requisition_modified_date, requisition.subproject_id AS requisition_subproject_id, requisition.core_time_period AS requisition_core_time_period, sum(budget.amount) AS sum_1 \nFROM budget, requisition \nWHERE budget.subproject_id = %(subproject_id_1)s AND budget.budget_transaction_type = %(budget_transaction_type_1)s AND order_no<=%(current_order_no)s GROUP BY budget.budget_line' {'current_order_no': 5, 'budget_transaction_type_1': 'Original Budget', 'subproject_id_1': 1}

Comment: Could you perhaps show us which errors you get?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Okay just did. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't include `Requisition` in your select list, but explicitly join it. Filter predicates are neater written using the mapped class attributes, compared to `text` expressions.

```
budgets_query = session.query(
    Budget.budget_line,
    func.sum(Budget.amount)
).\
    join(Requisition).\
    filter(Requisition.order_no <= current_order_no).\
    group_by(Budget.budget_line).\
    all()
```

Instead of the entity you could also pass the relationship `Budget.requisition` to `join()`, if you want.

Comment: you are brilliant. Works like charm. Thank you!